# ios cell content going beyond cell frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

This seems that it might be a brand new issue with iOS 7.1, but I'm noticing that my cells that contain date and ui pickers have a height of `1.0f` but the date pickers are being shown anyways. The picture is kind of confusing but basically after each cell, I have another cell with a height of `1.0f` which changes to `200.f` upon selection 'My week starts on...

This worked just fine on iOS 7.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've got the same problem on tableview cells..

Comment: @Joey see answer below..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you might solve your problem by calling [cell setClipsToBounds:YES] on each of your cells. This will cause the cell to stop showing anything outside its own bounds. Certainly worth a shot.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds

Comment: Congratulations, you just got the worlds easiest bounty. I cannot believe I didn't think of it. Then again, I assumed it was some weird issue with 7.1 - In any event, thank you!

Comment: I'll award the bounty tomorrow night :)

Comment: Glad to help! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes :)

Comment: This is how it should behave by default. The issue was with iOS 7.0.X.